# Reinforcement learning methodes that map continuous to continuous

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, economics

I am building a model where firms have to set prices and make production decisions. Prices are continuous and so are the decision variables. (inventory, last sales, prices...).

What reinforcement learning method can I use that maps continuous to continuous ?
Which python packages are there? If there are no python packages, I could write a wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/) machine learning library is what you're looking for. It is quite complex implementation of neural networks, but when you understand it you will get a really powerful tool.

PyBrain is a python library for neural network modeling. [Overview of the PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/) should get you a basic idea: at each timestamp you provides neural network with a set of continuous values and take out another set of continuous values. But more important is that you can evaluate the output and train your neural network.

All these steps - including network training - are already implemented in PyBrain.

Comment: The trouble is its documentation is sparse. Could you give me a hint what I could use for continous to continous?